# d3 v4 x-axis long labels are half hidden

Tags: d3.js, axis-labels

I am working on sample responsive d3 v4 bar chart, here the x-axis labels are bit long so it is not fully visible in the chart. Please check the Fiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/NayanaDas/w13y5kts/4/

JavaScript code:

```
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);


//define tooltip
var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([20, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Sales:</strong> <span style='font-weight:normal;color:red'>" + d.sales + "</span>";
  });

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg")
  //.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  //.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
        .attr("viewBox", "0 0 550 300")
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(tip);

// Add background color to the chart

svg.append("rect")
   .attr("x", 0)
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height)
   .attr("class","backbar");

// get the data
//d3.csv("sales.csv", function(error, data) {
//  if (error) throw error;
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select('#data_csv').text());
console.log(data);

// format the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.sales = +d.sales;
});

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.name;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
 return d.sales;
})]);

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.name);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.sales);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.sales);
  })
  .on('mouseover', tip.show)
  .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
  .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("fill", "#000")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-50)" );

 // add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

// add y-axis label
 svg.append("text")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  // this makes it easy to centre the text as the transform is applied to the anchor
   .attr("transform", "translate("+ (-margin.left/2) +","+(height/2)+")rotate(-90)")  // text is drawn off the screen top left, move down and out and rotate
   .text("Hours");
//});

$('#expandbtn').click(function (e) {
        $("#container").css("height","100%");
        $('#box').addClass('panel-fullscreen show');
        $('#compressbtn').removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
        $('#expandbtn').removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
 });

    $('#compressbtn').click(function (e) {
            $("#container").css("height","480px");
            $('#box').removeClass('panel-fullscreen');
            $('#expandbtn').removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
        $('#compressbtn').removeClass("show").addClass("hide");
    });
```

I have also added two buttons, on clicking expand button the chart will be displayed in full screen mode and on clicking compress button, chart will be back in normal size. Don't know if that has affected the display of x-axis labels. How can I make the long labels view-able?

Comment: There is an object named `margin`, with a property named `bottom`, just change it. Did you write that code? It doesn't;t seem so... in that case, make it clear with something like *"I'm building upon this code I found online"*, otherwise we will have an incorrect idea of your knowledge level.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip. I'm not an expert in d3 visualization, that's why I clearly stated that i'm working a sample code. Sorry if it gave you a wrong idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your svg viewBox attribuite to `0 0 550 550`.

The first two values are the X and Y coordinates of the upper left corner of the displayed area, the last two are the width and height. `viewBox` is set only by attribute.
[How it works](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/qXRBBJ)

Also check what is `preserveAspectRatio` values and [how they work](https://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/RZVqJv)

Comment: when I changed the margin, bottom property it was fixed, but setting 'preserveAspectRatio' properly, the chart alignment look good. Thank you

Comment: @Nayana_Das, Can you accept the answer, if it helped? :)

Comment: It was not the answer to the question, but it did help, that's why i didn't accept it as answer but up-voted it.